# redux-observable not exported createEpicMiddleware

Tags: redux-observable

I am using redux-observable in Ionic2 rc0 and getting below error, any idea?

```
Error: Module /Volumes/data/test/node_modules/redux-observable/lib/index.js does not 
export createEpicMiddleware (imported by /Volumes/data/test/.tmp/store/index.js)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Ionic in years, but a quick look at the Ionic issue tracker suggests this is related to Rollup and affects numerous third party libraries.

[ionic#8322](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8322) contains numerous examples of this problem, and looks like it then moved to [ionic-app-scripts#68](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/68) with the latest [conclusions appearing to be here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/68#issuecomment-251779067)

If you find there's something on redux-observable's end we can do to make it easier, please let us know! We do [maintain a TypeScript definition](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/index.d.ts) included with the package.

As a temporary workaround you *might* be able to access the file directly with:

```js
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable/lib/createEpicMiddleware';

// note the path! reaching into lib directly
```

It might not work though, because I doubt TypeScript will correlate this file with the type definition in our index.d.ts.

Comment: now it say's

error TS2307: Cannot find module 'redux-observable/lib/createEpicMiddleware'.